# Google Action does not have trained NLU model (No trained NLU model found.)

Tags: google-assistant, actionbuilder

I am currently in the process of migrating from an older Dialogflow agent to a new ActionBuilder agent. Going well so far (translated into a new action to wrap things up before I am gonna push the changes to the old action), but it suddenly stopped working in the Simulator.

It crashes after the initial welcome, no trace on any scene migrations and it doesn't hit the fulfillment.

The logs simply state:

**No trained NLU model found.**

Note: It did work for a few days before that.

I did rename a few intents and scenes and reorganized some transitions before that.

I already tried to trigger a new training process by changing some phrases but that didn't change anything (it did show the training indicator tho).
I wonder if anyone has any idea, maybe on how to retrain the whole agent/NLU model or something similar?

Comment: Have you found made any progress on this? I'm running into the same thing, and this is the only result that shows up.

Comment: I am afraid not. It did resolve itself last time, but I am now in the same situation again. I don't think I did anything last time to have the NLU model available again (except for  triggering some training phases now and again by changing things, but that did not seem to directly help or anything).

Comment: Still nothing here? I've been blocked by this for days

Comment: I reached out to Google, and then said it's a known issue. They're working to resolve it now.

Comment: This seems to be up and working again. [Solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71233079/1449223) Might be worth marking this question as a duplicate?