# No trained NLU model found (Actions on Google)

Tags: actions-on-google

We are developing boot using Actions on google SDK, we migrated our dev project UAT and all of sudden its stoped working. Previously we are using same approach and its working every time. Bot respond once for initial phrase after that it stop responding. it say Sorry, [Bot name] is not responding. Please try again later. After tracing the logs we found its sending below error. Please guide us what is wrong with our approach.

```
{
labels: {3}
type: "assistant_action"
}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "No trained NLU model found."
timestamp: "2022-02-17T12:00:35.499117218Z"
trace: ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue resolved now, Google resolved this issue we need to follow these steps. Open your project-> Go to Main invocation-> Edit it by adding prompt message->Save the changes-> Now NLU model trining in progress will show up at bottom, wait until its execution end. -> After that try testing your action, it will work  [Please see this for more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0AJY.png)